# Scala char to int conversion

Tags: scala

```
def multiplyStringNumericChars(list: String): Int = {
  var product = 1;
  println(s"The actual thing  + $list")
  list.foreach(x => { println(x.toInt);
                      product = product * x.toInt;
                    });

  product;
};
```

This is a function that takes a String like `12345` and should return the result of `1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5`. However, I'm getting back doesn't make any sense. What is the implicit conversion from `Char` to `Int` actually returning?

It appears to be adding `48` to all the values. If instead I do `product = product * (x.toInt - 48)` the results are correct.

Comment: For a character, toInt returns the corresponding character code. Use x.asDigit to get the integer corresponding to a digit (this works for up to base 36 if you include letters).

Answer (score 93, accepted):

It does make sense: that is the way [how characters encoded in ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII): 0 char maps to decimal 48, 1 maps to 49 and so on. So basically when you convert char to int, all you need to do is to just subtract '0':

```
scala> '1'.toInt
// res1: Int = 49

scala> '0'.toInt
// res2: Int = 48

scala> '1'.toInt - 48
// res3: Int = 1

scala> '1' - '0'
// res4: Int = 1
```

Or just use `x.asDigit`, as @Reimer said

```
scala> '1'.asDigit
// res5: Int = 1
```