# Scala: convert each digit in a string to an integer

Tags: string, scala, integer

I want to convert each digit in a number to an int. Here is my code

```
for (in <- lines) { 
    for (c <- in) {
        val ci = c.toInt
        if (ci == 0) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

The result I get is the ascii code, i.e. a 1 gives 49. I'm looking for the value 1.
The answer is trivial, I know. I'm trying to pull myself up with my own bootstraps until my Scala course begins in two weeks. Any assistance gratefully accepted.

Comment: Can you please give an example input, i.e. `"1234"` should return the number, `1234`?

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I solved the problem. asDigit was what I was looking for. I wanted 1234 to become 1 and 2 and 3 and 4 so I could process each digit separately. I was getting 49, 50, 51, etc. It would have been easy enough to subtract ascii zero but I felt that would be a poor start to my budding Scala career if I stooped that low.

Comment: How should negative numbers be handled? In other words, what's the output of `-1234`?

Comment: For my problem there was no need to handle anything but digits, so the solution is adequate. I'm using Alvin Alexander's Scala Cookbook as a guide. For your question I can use
Integer.parseInt("-1234", 10)
(assuming base 10). Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is:

```
for(in <- lines) {
    in.toString.map(_.asDigit).foreach { i =>
        if(i == 1) {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

And more compact w/ output:

```
lines.foreach(in => in.toString.map(_.asDigit).filter(_ == 1).foreach(i => println(s"found $i in $in.")))
```

If lines is already a collection of Strings, omit the .toString on in.toString.

Comment: asDigit is the answer. Many thanks. I found the question has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16241923/scala-char-to-int-conversion
I didn't see it because I searched for string and not char.

Answer (score 1):

You can have this:

```
val number = 123456
//convert Int to String and do transformation for each character to Digit(Int)
val digitsAsList = number.toString.map(_.asDigit)
```

This will result to digitizing the number. Then with that Collection, you can do anything from filtering, mapping, zipping: you can checkout the the List api on this page: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.collection.immutable.List

Hope that's help.